# nodejs, expressjs serving PHP files

Tags: node.js, webclient, express, socket.io

Ok I've been playing around with nodejs, expressjs and socket.io to create some applications.  But now im coming to the stage where i want to take things a bit further.

I have noticed a few node apps using PHP for twitter auth on their client side. When I attempt to rename my client.html file to client.php and restart the server it throws up a blank page with this

```
Cannot GET /
```

How do would serve php files or would i do twitter auto using js?

This is my NodeJS server.js

```
var http = require('http'),  
    express = require('express');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.listen(1234);
console.log("server started on port :1234");
```

Comment: node.js is not a PHP interpreter. If you think you can just rename the file with `.php` and it'll magically be executed, you're not thinking this through...

Answer (score 7):

As already noted, node.js itself won't interpret php files for you. Available options are:

- have nginx in front of node and reverse proxy all request you want to process in node from it
- proxy php requests from node to php-capable server
- spawn php process on each request in node
- make fastcgi link to php-fastcgi using [node fastcgi protocol parser](https://github.com/billywhizz/node-fastcgi-parser)

Answer (score 3):

Uh, skip PHP entirely and integrate [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) into your app.

Answer (score 0):

PHP-EXPRESS should do. Just install the package and follow the docs.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-express