# Express.js serve legacy links (.php)

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to port a PHP application to node/express. 
Right now I am facing the problem to serve some legacy links like `www.example.com/test.php`

I get the following error from express:

```
Cannot GET /test.php
```

How can I serve `.php` routes with express/node?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplication of [nodejs, expressjs serving PHP files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836842/nodejs-expressjs-serving-php-files) (if you mean serve like php preprocess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to /test.php as any other URL:

```
app.get('/test.php',function(req,res){
  res.redirect('/YourNewRouter')
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved it with `app.get('*', function(req, res) { ... })`